# How to exclude project name from NSStringFromClass in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, logging, nslog, swift5

I am logging `class` names and `enums` in `Swift` project. I saw its appending project name as prefix in each of instances string description. For example,

I created extension of `NSObject`,

```
public extension NSObject {

    var classTag: String {
        return NSStringFromClass(type(of: self))
    }
}
```

I am using in in `AppDelegate`,

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    func testFunc() {
        print(classTag, "Testing log")
    }
}
```

Its output is,

> TestProject.AppDelegate Testing log

How can I remove `TestProject.` and print only `AppDelegate`?

NB: When I am printing or logging enums its behaving same (i.e. appending Project name automatically in description)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use **`String(describing:)`** instead of `NSStringFromClass` like so,

```
public extension NSObject {
    var classTag: String {
        return String(describing: type(of: self)) //here....
    }
}
```

Comment: Will it cover everything that `NSStringFromClass` covers?

Comment: Since you want to get the type name as a `String`, it will work for all those cases.

Comment: yes it worked for classes but for enum it did not work.